# How I can inspect that a temporary file has been created and sucessfuly written from an okHttp3 client?

Tags: java, android, temporary-files

I attempt to download a tarball using okHttp3:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://example.com/myfile.tar.gz").build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    ResponseBody downloadedTar = response.body();

    // Status code checks goes here
    if (downloadedTar == null) {
       throw new SettingsFailedException();
    }

    File file = File.createTempFile(System.currentTimeMillis()+"_file", ".tar.gz", getContext().getCacheDir());
     FileOutputStream download = new FileOutputStream(file);

     download.write(downloadedTar.body().bytes());
     download.flush();
     download.close();
```

But how I can check whether the temp file has been created without the need to write some code? Is there some sort of tool where I can inspect app's cache dir?

Comment: Does Device Explorer of Android Studio not show this directory? Otherwise just change path of your temp file so that file managers have access.

Comment: The idea was to make an in-app temporary file so I can e4xtract some data from it.

Comment: And your other idea was to inspect the cache dir. Now there are no tools for it. So i suggested to use another directory for which there are tools. I dont understand your reaction. You can extract data there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if via adb as root:

```
adb root
adb shell
```

On the shell then run:

```
ls -l ^path^
```

The `^path^` value can be obtained via breakpoint upon:

```
     FileOutputStream download = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

And evaluating the `file.toString()`

Or via a log entry underneath the:

```
Log.d("Debug",file.toString());
```

And look on Logcat for it (You'll have a better change if you filter by `Debug`).

---

## Note:

In order to use breakpoint you'll need to:

1. Select the line as image shows

[image: Select Breakpoint]

2. Then click on dug icon:
   [image: Select Debug option]

A more detailed example you'll find in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2_Mtx9xzF8